# The function names in the for loop doesn't work R

Tags: r

I have a group of data.frame with the same dimensions of column, but different numbers of row.

```
DATA.FRAME.A
Column_A     Column_B     Column_C     Column_D      Column_E
2001-02-20      10           11           5              8

DATA.FRAME_B
Column_F     Column_G      Column_W    Column_T      Column_Q
2008-08-7        50           21          10             50

DATA.FRAME_C
Column_H     Column_J      Column_K    Column_S      Column_P
2001-02-02      13           15           61             7
```

My purpose is to make the first row the same for all data.frame

I wrote this cycle for to make my code simple.

```
t <- list(DATA.FRAME_A, DATA.FRAME_B, DATA.FRAME_C)
for (i in t ) {
  names[i] <- c("Data", "Open", "Max", "Minimun", "Close")
   }
```

R doesn't give me any type of error.

Where I was wrong?

I'd like to have these results

```
DATA.FRAME.A
   Data        Open          Max       Minimun      Close
2001-02-20      10           11           5              8

DATA.FRAME_B
 Data           Open          Max       Minimun      Close
2008-08-7        50           21          10             50

DATA.FRAME_C
 Data          Open          Max       Minimun      Close
2001-02-02      13           15           61             7
```

Thanks in advance.

Francesco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider `lapply`, part of the *apply* family that are helpful iterative functions that return same number of elements as input and in your case can return the modified data frame elements. Even consider `setNames()` being a right-hand function to return the named object.

```
t <- list(DATA.FRAME_A, DATA.FRAME_B, DATA.FRAME_C)

# ITERATE THROUGH EACH DF OF t, RENAMING COLUMNS, RETURNING MODIFIED DF
new_t <- lapply(t, function(i) setNames(i, c("Data", "Open", "Max", "Minimun", "Close"))

 # RESULTS
lapply(new_t, head)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! It works. I'm learning R and I have to deep the lapply family

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
t <- c("DATA.FRAME.A", "DATA.FRAME.B", "DATA.FRAME.C")
for (i in 1:length(t)) {
    names(get(t[i])) <- c("Data", "Open", "Max", "Minimun", "Close")
}
```

Comment: Thanky you for your answer, but dosen't work. 
R gives me this error: Error in get(`*tmp*`) : object 'NA' not found

Comment: Did you replace the `_` in the data.frame name with a `.` dot? Seems like the object in the character vector `t` does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you wrote, the loop variable `i` will be each of list `t`'s individual items (not the *index* into the list, but the list items themselves). In addition, `colnames` would be more straightforward for this purpose. A better way to write this loop would be:

```
t <- list(DATA.FRAME_A, DATA.FRAME_B, DATA.FRAME_C)
for (i in 1:length(t)) {
  colnames(t[[i]]) <- c("Data", "Open", "Max", "Minimun", "Close")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

sub-setting a list in R requires double square brackets

```
t <- list(DATA.FRAME_A, DATA.FRAME_B, DATA.FRAME_C)
for (i in seq_along(t) ) {
  names(t[[i]]) <- c("Data", "Open", "Max", "Minimun", "Close")
 }
```

What you did was not an error, you modify i in your for loop, but i is a temp variable created for the for loop, and is destroyed after each iteration, rather than modifying your list

Comment: Thank for your explication and for your example.